# How can I Import settings from a MobaXterm.ini file to MobaXterm?

Tags: mobaxterm

I've installed MobaXterm in my computer, but I can´t find a way to import the settings from the mobaXterm.ini.

I've alreay read the documentation (I've tried, at least, with my bad english) but I couldn´t find the solution.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem after trying to import a MobaXterm.ini from a computer running v12.4 to another computer running v22.3.

What worked for me on new computer was:

1. Close/Quit MobaXterm
2. Copy MobaXterm.ini to C:\Users<accountname>\AppData\Roaming\MobaXterm\
3. Restart MobaXterm

After that, it will start up using your MobaXterm.ini and continue updating it each time you quit MobaXterm.

Once you get this working, you should export your sessions to a file called "MobaXterm Sessions.mxtsessions" by right clicking on "User Sessions" and selecting "Export all sessions to file".

There is also a way to export the entire configuration to a ".mobaconf" file by clicking "Settings/Export configuration".

You can use the exported files as backups and re-import them later if needed.

Comment: You might have to delete the entries "SlashDir=" and "HomeDir=" if they have changed

Answer (score 1):

[image: Files to be copied from old to new version - Simple configuration change will do the trick]

Coping the 2 files mentioned in image will do the trick. It will help in transferring the configurations from old to new version.